# How to check this promise state, when programming a new promise? js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I am programming a new promise, it has many different conditions that call `reject()` or `resolve()` related to their state, also I know that the promise state will set with the first call to `reject()` | `resolve()`.
My question is:
Is there any native (build-in) way to get the promise state?
The following is a demonstrative-code:

```
exports.addStatement = function (db, description, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        validator.validateStatement(description, data)
        .then(function (data) {
            //......
            if(cnd1)
               resolve(res);
            if(cnd2)
               reject(err);
            //......
            //How to check if this promise is rejected or resolved yet? 

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            reject(err);
        })
    })
};
```

Comment: That's not how promises work. 
Seems like you've missed the whole concept of promises.
You can only use `then()` and `catch()`,  only after the promise has been returned from the function

Comment: new Promise state is related to an inner promise, it works.

Comment: Two remarks. Why don't you just use `if () {} else if() {} else {}` or just `return resolve();`? That way there is no need to know the promise state at all and your code gets cleaner. And second: Why do you even need `new Promise` when `validator.validateStatement` already returns a promise?

Comment: If you want to know whether you just called resolve or reject yet inside your own function, then just keep your own flag that indicates that.  But, probably you could just use `if/else if /else` to know whether you already hit  one of your conditions or not.

Comment: Also, your using an anti-pattern when creating a new outer promise here.  You can just return the promise that `validator.validateStatement()` already returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly examine the state of a promise.  That's not how they work.  You can use `.then()` or `.catch()` on them with a callback to get notified.

Or, in your specific case, you can probably change the way your code is structured to remove the [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) of creating an unnecessary outer promise and switching your logic to if/else if/else.

Here's the cleaned up code:

```
exports.addStatement = function (db, description, data) {
    return validator.validateStatement(description, data)
        .then(function (data) {
            //......
            if(cnd1) {
               // make res be the resolved value of the promise
               return res;
            } else if(cnd2) {
               // make promise become rejected with err as the reason
               throw err;
            } else {
               // decide what else to do here
            }
        })
    })
};
```

If you couldn't make an if/else work for you, the above structure should still work because both the `return` and the `throw` terminate the execution of the `.then()` handler.  So, the only code that continues after them is code that has not yet set the resolved/rejected value for the current promise so you don't have to look at the state of the promise to know that.  If the code gets past the `return` and `throw` and is still executing, then neither of those was executed and the resolved/rejected value of the current promise is still unset.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I change my way and remove the `new Promise()` line, but it fails, I think the point is the first `promise.then` runs an async code, so the second `promise.then` will be called with an undefined argument.

Comment: @RezaAfzalan - It is perfectly acceptable to chain promises and `.then()` handlers are always called asynchronously.  Promises are bulit for that situation.  You will have to show more of your real code (instead of this pseudo code) for us to help you further.  The direction is conceptually correct.  We need to see your actual code to know what else you are doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can check it: https://github.com/DANA-Laboratory/modproject/blob/refactory/app/models-sqlite3/LearningX/statement.js#L57

Comment: Also it is how I test it: https://github.com/DANA-Laboratory/modproject/blob/refactory/test/testlearningx.js#L345

Comment: It fails when I remove new Promise: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb0dce30cf75d760f62881e739b2112e

Comment: @RezaAfzalan -That's because the code in your gist is using async operations inside the `.then()` handler that are not using promises.  The whole promise system of return values and error handling breaks down if you don't use promises for all your async operations.  You did not disclose that issue in your question.  You should use the promise interface for your database, not the callback interface.